# Почему нулевой Executor

Tags: java, android

В общем проблема у меня очень мистическая.
Делаю блокнот, и когда хочу удалить заметку после запуска активности все работает и проблем нет, но когда открываю другую активность и возвращаюсь на старую при попытке удалить получаю краш приложения и эту ошибку.

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.concurrent.Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
```

Как у меня все устроено **MainActivity** -> при долгом нажатии на заметку вызываю **choseNote(dialog)** -> (через интерфейс при нажатии на пункт удалить вызываю метод с активности (**deleteNote(note)**), а он в свою очередь вызывает метод с **presenter deleteNote(note)** -> **presenter** -> вызывает методы с репозитория которые переносят заметку в корзину (**moveToNoteTrash()**) и удаляет заметку с таблицы (**deleteNote()**).

**presenter.deleteNote(note)**

```
 @Override
public void deleteNote(Note note){
   trashRepository.moveToTrash(note);
   notesRepository.deleteNote(note);
}
```

**trashRepository.moveToTrash(note)**

```
    public void moveToTrash(Note note) {
    Runnable runnable = () ->{
       trashDao.moveToTrash(note.getTitle(), note.getValue(), note.getDate());

    };
    executor.execute(runnable);
}
```

**noteRepository.deleteNote(Note)**

```
    public void deleteNote(Note note) {
    Runnable runnable = () -> noteDao.deleteNote(note);
    executor.execute(runnable);
}
```

**noteDao,trashDao**

```
 @Delete void deleteNote(Note note);

  @Query("INSERT INTO trash (title,value,date,type) VALUES (:title,:value,:date, 'note')")
void moveToTrash(String title, String value, long date);
```

Comment: Только `null` у вас не `Runnable`, а `Executor`

Comment: @woesss заметка удаляеться, только появилась новая ошибка   Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.pasich.mynotes.data.trash.source.dao.TrashDao.moveToTrash(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long)' on a null object reference
        at com.pasich.mynotes.data.trash.source.TrashRepository.lambda$moveToTrash$0$com-pasich-mynotes-data-trash-source-TrashRepository(TrashRepository.java:38)

Comment: Ну теперь у вас `trashDao` `null`. У вас какие-то проблемы с инициализацией репозитория, вероятно она у вас условная и не выполняется при повторном открытии `MainActivity` (а я подозреваю у вас именно открытие, а не возврат).  Покажите эти моменты в коде: вызов другой активности, возврат из неё, инициализацию полей репозитория, кто, где и когда её вызывает.

Comment: @woesss закрытие активности второй активности происходит с помощю finish(); Но другие функции репозитория срабатывают, нормально.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар куда-то закатился и код я ваш не вижу, что вы там делаете известно только вам.

Comment: @woesss https://github.com/pasichDev/testREpo.git

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138508/discussion-between-andrii-pasichnik-and-woesss).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена с помощью пользователя @woesss.

Presenter второго activty удалял репозиторий при вызове destroy().